# OS X Swift WebView disable scrolling

Tags: macos, swift

How do you disable scrolling in a webview in OS X?
I found
`webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false;`
but that is not working in swift.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

As long as the web isn't using javascript scrollbar or overflow property in css file this should do the work

```
webView.mainFrame.frameView.allowsScrolling = false;
```

Tested on my website without those fancy things mentioned above and it worked.